# ionic 5 reorder scrolling issue

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll, ionic5

I have an issue with ion-reorder, i have implemented long press to start reorder and i have an issue when scrolling. i want to ignore the long press while scrolling and only address long press when scrolling has stopped.

my long press code is:

```
import {
  Directive,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLongPress]'
})
export class LongPressDirective {

  pressing: boolean;
  longPressing: boolean;
  timeout: any;
  // interval: number;
  interval: NodeJS.Timeout;

  @Output()
  onLongPress = new EventEmitter();

  @Output()
  onLongPressing = new EventEmitter();

  @HostBinding('class.press')
  get press() { return this.pressing; }

  @HostBinding('class.longpress')
  get longPress() { return this.longPressing; }

  @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])


  onMouseDown(event) {
    this.pressing = true;
    this.longPressing = false;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.longPressing = true;
      this.onLongPress.emit(event);
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.onLongPressing.emit(event);
      }, 50);
    }, 1500);
  }

  @HostListener('touchend')
  @HostListener('mouseup')
  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  endPress() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.longPressing = false;
    this.pressing = false;
  }

}
```

thanks..

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: I want to know how to prevent from the long press to occure when scrolling. I use this directive to handle long press to activate ion-reorder, and while i am scrolling if the finger stays long enough it enter the reorder instead of continue scrolling, reorder should only happen when statticly pressing the screen for a period of time